# Entity Framework autoincrement key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm facing an issue of duplicated incremental field on a concurrency scenario.

I'm using EF as the ORM tool, attempting to insert an entity with a field that acts as a incremental INT field. Basically this field is called "SequenceNumber", where each new record before insert, will read the database using MAX to get the last SequenceNumber, append +1 to it, and saves the changes.

Between the getting of last `SequenceNumber` and saving, that's where the concurrency is happening.

I'm not using `ID` for `SequenceNumber` as it is not a unique constraint, and may reset on certain conditions such as monthly, yearly, etc.

```
InvoiceNumber       | SequenceNumber | DateCreated
INV00001_08_14      | 1              | 25/08/2014
INV00001_08_14      | 1              | 25/08/2014 <= (concurrency is creating two SeqNo 1)
INV00002_08_14      | 2              | 25/08/2014
INV00003_08_14      | 3              | 26/08/2014
INV00004_08_14      | 4              | 27/08/2014
INV00005_08_14      | 5              | 29/08/2014
INV00001_09_14      | 1              | 01/09/2014 <= (sequence number reset)
```

Invoice number is formatted based on the `SequenceNumber`.

After some research I've ended up with these possible solutions, but want to know the best practice

1. Pessimistic Concurrency, locking the table from any reads until the current transaction is completed (not fancy of this idea as I guess performance will be of a great impact?)
2. Create a stored procedure solely for this purpose, does select and insert on a single statement as such concurrency is at minimum (would prefer a EF based approach if possible)

==============================

**EDIT**

Another solution that I've thought of is to make the **InvoiceNumber** a **Unique Constraint**, so on cases of duplicate entries it would throw the Unique Constraint Violation errors, catch it, and reattempt to get a new SequenceNumber and InvoiceNumber to reinsert to the DB.

Comment: Is this supposed to be table key or something? About locking table until transaction is completed. Yes u can do it just set isolation level to Serializable. But this can crush your application performance (and probably will rly not good idea).

Comment: You can call an SP using EF... (about 2nd point).

Comment: Can you make `InvoiceNumber, SequenceNumber, DateCreated` a unique constraint?

Comment: @Laurence can't make it a unique constraint as SequenceNumber will be reset on conditions

Comment: @TommyOng That's why I suggested a combination of three columns, rather than one.

Comment: @Laurence making it a Unique Constraint won't help much as I still need to deal with duplicated InvoiceNumber on concurrency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who may face the same challenge as I have, what I finalized on was to make the InvoiceNumber a constraint, and deal with the UniqueConstraintException and reattempt to get the InvoiceNumber.

To avoid endless loops (if it ever happens), added a "retry" counter.

```
        int retry = 5;
        try
        {
            // Get new purchase order number from service

            Invoice.InvoiceNumber = GetNewPurchaseOrderNumber();

            // Explicit set state as Added
            Invoice.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;

            _uow.Repository<Invoice>().InsertGraph(Invoice);
            _uow.Save();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            retry--;
            if (null == ex.InnerException) throw;

            var innerException = ex.InnerException.InnerException
                                   as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;
            if (innerException != null &&
                   (
                       innerException.Number == 2627 ||
                       innerException.Number == 2601)
                       && retry > 0
                   )
            {
                // Get new Invoice Number from service
                Invoice.InvoiceNumber = GetNewPurchaseOrderNumber();

                _uow.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

use a fake table/entity with an identity key.

Before inserting an invoice insert in the fake table to get an ID.
Use the ID, not as a FK but as a SequenceNumber

For the reset: truncate the fake table.

Predictable problem: you may have hole in the sequence, depending on insertion errors.

be aware of [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) since sql server 2012. BTW, if you think the idea is good, also [upvote on datavoice](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6344363-sequence)

=====

a sql sequence can be used as a default value through a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Invoice
ADD CONSTRAINT DefSequence DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR InvoiceSeq) 
    FOR SequenceNumber;
GO
```

by setting SequenceNumber as a `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` it could be perfect.

Comment: @tschmit007 thanks for the suggestions. Having a fake table / entity is abit overdoing I guess, in my scenario as I didn't point out that there's about 30+ fields in this table, and also 5 of other such tables that needs to handle the SequenceNumber.

Comment: in this case, the sequence seems to be a good solution (if available).

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic concurrency means that there are no locks stablished. The changes to the DB are checked at the end of the operation. If nothign else modified something that affected the operation, it means it went fine. If someone else modified something that affected the operation, it will throw an exception. (The name comes from the fact that you're optimistic in the hope that nothing else modifies the data while you're ueing it).

An stored procedure is a good solution. Why not using it? - Remember that you must enclose the procedure code inside a transaction. If not, you're not protected against concurrency problems.

[You can modify the data inside a transaction directly from EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).

A trigger would also work. However, I don't recommend using it: it's very difficult to detect that it exists, if you don't know that it's there.

In any case, a lock by a transaction should not mean a performance problem if you only do the very simple operation of reading a row, and writing other. Don't try to solve a performance problem before it exists.

**EDIT**
The performance problems are created by long-running transactions, i.e. transactions that take a long time to execute for example because they read or write a lot of data (for example updating a field that contains an aggreate of a child table with many related rows, or looking up data in a huge table with millions of rows without an availabe index). If you keep the sequence in a single table with a single row, reading it is blazingly fast, and, hopefully, writing a row in another table, is also very, very fast, specially if the clustered index  (by default the primary key it's the clustered index) allows to write the row at the end of the table, as it should in a crowded table. To ensure that the data is wirtten at the end of the table each new row should be the last in the clustered index.

Comment: Apologies, I meant Pessimistic Concurrency, thanks for the correction